# Mobx Computed with Arguments (computedFn) and TypeScript - what's this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

The following example https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html raises an error using TypeScript.

```
// Parameterized computed views:
// Create computed's and store them in a cache
import { observable } from "mobx"
import { computedFn } from "mobx-utils"

class Todos {
  @observable todos = []

  getAllTodosByUser = computedFn(function getAllTodosByUser(userId) {
    return this.todos.filter(todo => todo.user === userId))
  })
}
```

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
>
> An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.

Setting tsconfig's `noImplicitThis` to false will workaround on this but my intention is to keep `noImplicitThis` set to `true`.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting `this: Todos` will fix it. TypeScript will not complain and the `this` will be correctly typed. Notice that the TS compiler will remove the `this` parameter when compiling to JavaScript.

```
// Parameterized computed views:
// Create computed's and store them in a cache
import { observable } from "mobx"
import { computedFn } from "mobx-utils"

class Todos {
  @observable todos: ITodo[] = []

  getAllTodosByUser = computedFn(function getAllTodosByUser(this: Todos, userId: ITodo[]) {
    return this.todos.filter(todo => todo.user === userId))
  })
}
```